# Driver issue? This device is currently in use

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, connection

When trying to safely remove a connected USB device, I get the error "The device is currently in use. Close any programs or windows that might be using the device, and then try again." **exactly 1 time**. The next time I try to safely remove the device, it disconnects properly.

When I try to eject the USB device in the File Manager, this doesn't occur and it disconnects as it should. I should note that everything is closed and Windows is not using the USB in any way.

I am using an HP Probook 650 G1 running Windows 10 x64 (build 10240). All USB ports are USB 3.0 ports.

I guess this might be a driver needing an update. The problem is that I don't know which driver this might be.